# Why left shift instruction has two names (SAL and SHL) in x86-64 ISA?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instruction-set, instructions, mnemonics

I know that logical left shift and arithmetic left shift perform the same operation of multiplying the number with 2<sup>k</sup> when shifted by k bits. In x86-64 ISA, there are two instructions for logical left shift `shl` and arithmetic left shift `sal`. When both instructions are doing the same job, what is the need of creating second instruction?